# Where should I ask a question related to life education?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question related to education, but not related specifically to academic education or pedagogy. I think it may be considered "education for life" - how to deal with situations that can appear in groups or classes.

For example, how do I explain a group of kids which I lead about a particular medical problem that I have without terriffying them? How do I deal with bullying? (the second is much broader).

Comment: It might help if you told us a little more about the question itself.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I edited the question.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not an SE site for it, only this [Area 51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82415/educators) - which you already found. If you need the answers any time soon, I guess you could try [Parenting.SE]. Disclaimer: I'm not active on Parenting, you'll have to decide for yourself if it is on-topic there.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Alright, thank you.